# Angular Form Not Available When ng-init runs?

Tags: angularjs

I can not access the form in my controller. In addition, I can not even access `this` which shows `undefined`.

Route:

```
  $routeProvider.when '/deployments/deploy',
    templateUrl: 'deployments/partials/form.html'
    controller: 'deploy.new'
```

HTML:

```
  <form class="form-inline" ng-submit="submit()" name="form" ng-init="setFormScope(this)">
    <div class="pure-g clear">
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('infrastructure.deployments')
.controller 'deploy.new', ($scope, $q, $location, ) ->
  $scope.setFormScope = (this) ->
    console.log this
```

UPDATE:

If I use `<div  ng-init="setFormScope(form)"></div>` is undefined. But If I use `<div  ng-mouseup="setFormScope(form)"></div>` then I get the form object. Why isn't the form ready/available when `ng-init` runs?

Comment: Are you using coffeescript?

Comment: yes, not my preference though.

Comment: I don think you can pass `this` in an angular expression.

Comment: change to `$scope.setFormScope = () ->
    console.log this`

Comment: please, add a plunker.

Comment: I've never used `ng-init` in this way. The form is not created when `ng-init` runs. `ng-init != onload`. Let's back up. What are you trying to do?

Comment: ng-init is one of the most misused directives in angular.  It **is not** a form initializer; It really only has one purpose, which is to initialize special params on ng-repeat.  Form setup should be done in your controller.

Answer (score 3):

`this` is a reserved word. You cannot (or you shouldn't) use it as a parameter name.

`setFormScope(this)` is an angular expression, it's not really javascript, it's evaluated by angular and `this` is not known to it in the given context so it evaluates to `undefined`.

To pass the form, you can use its name `setFormScope(form)` or you can even access it directly from the controller because it's accessible on the scope: `$scope.form` (again, using its name).